# BGE: How to apply colour to a certain face with python?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

Lets say i have a xy plane that is subdivided 10 by 10.  Now, how can I apply a colour to a, for instance, 5x6 set of faces on the plane using python in the game engine?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to apply coloir to that face in-game you can add different material to it without python- in materials tabe add ne material to mesh on the left of the list of materials. Than set that material to the color you want and go in edit mode. Than select the face you want to be colored in that color and select it(only). After that stay in edit mode and go to materials tab. Selec the material you want to apply on your face and than press `assign` under list of materials in materials tab!

Comment: I have already tryed that. now im looking if it is possible to do it this way.